# Node js on ubuntu 16.04 - Should I store the node js project in the website's document root?

Tags: node.js, apache, ubuntu-16.04

I followed this instruction to install node js:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

I run it on apache though.

They (https://www.1and1.com/cloud-community/learn/application/misc/set-up-a-nodejs-app-for-a-website-with-apache-on-ubuntu-1604/) suggest to store the node js project in /var/www/html/

```
/var/www/html/nodejs/hello.js
```

Is that recommended or where should I store the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your application wherever you want.  Node.js doesn't care.

However, you really *don't* want to put your application (or anything else you don't want shared to the world) in your web server's document root.  Otherwise it's trivial to download your source code.

I usually clone my repo to `/opt`, but it doesn't have to be there.  It can be wherever you want.

Comment: But what if I want to run an application (when its done) on the web server's document root ... what do I need to pay intention if I want to do so?

Comment: @PhilippM Why would you want to do that?  Sure, if you want everybody to be able to download your source code, you could, but for what reason?  If that's what you wanted, it'd be easier if you put your code up on Bitbucket or GitHub.